# Banner video overlapping the main navbar only in the chrome browser

Tags: html, css, css-position, overlapping

I am creating a web landing page with the use of flex-box-properties. It is working fine on all other browsers except the chrome.this div `.container-fluid.mian-top-bar` is overlapped by the `.section-second-banner.flxx` section and its video.

Comment: add `.section-second-banner {overflow: hidden;}` since you are using `position:absolute` on the video

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Set height for the top container-fluid e.g. `height:100px`.

Comment: still not working after adding the height

Comment: and on all other browsers it is working fine but why not on the chrome ?